# Huge and disproportionate menu and icons in KDE Plasma

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I'm using Arch Linux with KDE Plasma and all menus and windows icons became huge after an update

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Not surprising given the currently Qt5/6 licensing debacle. Suggest posting to [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/) or to the [Arch-general mailing list](https://lists.archlinux.org/listinfo/) if you are unsuccessful on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @kaylum you're right! I'm sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this link, so they deserve the credit:
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/537347-KDE-Fonts-icons-and-menus-too-big-or-disproportionate

Basically, there was a missing configuration in this file /etc/sddm.conf
This is the needed configuration:

[X11]
EnableHiDPI=true

Comment: God love SuSE (formerly opensuse, unless they changed their minds again) for decent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

change this file **/etc/sddm.conf** to the next config

```
[X11]
ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 96
```

I use a TV for watching KDE and it helped me.